# Why no more error messages after importing QGIS modules into python?

Tags: pyqgis

I have a problem when writing python code whilst including the qgis modules. As can be seen below, when I usually call a variable that does not exist (for example), I receive the usual error message. Just what you'd expect to happen. But after having imported qgis.core and qgis.utils into python, all error messages disappear (see below). This obviously makes code debugging extremely tedious, as I never get any indication, why and where a code failed.

```
>>> print this_variable_does_not_exist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'this_variable_does_not_exist' is not defined
>>> from qgis.core import *
>>> from qgis.utils import *
>>> print this_variable_does_not_exist
>>>                          (<< why is there no error here?)
```

How can I stop this "error-suppressing" behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `qgis.utils` module overrides the exception handler so that it can show custom Python error output in a Qt dialog in the running GUI application ([see module code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/utils.py#L59-L88)).

To remove the override, do the following:

```python
>>> from qgis import utils
>>> print x
>>> utils.uninstallErrorHook()  
>>> print x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Or, following your code sample:

```python
>>> from qgis.utils import *
>>> print x
>>> uninstallErrorHook()  
>>> print x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: qgis.utils isn't really meant to be used by anyone expect QGIS itself.

Comment: @Nathan: Thanks for your input. I was given a code that loads this module, I will talk about this issue with the person who programmed it in.